# Precise evaluation of ProductLog in a Contourplot

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I have to plot the Electrical Field of a half infinity Capacitor.

The mathematical Function to this is:

```
\[Phi]re[{x_, y_}] := With[{z = x + I y}, Re[z - 1 - ProductLog[Ceiling[(y - Pi)/(2 Pi)], Exp[z - 1]]]]
```

The Function ProductLog[k,z] has as input the "usual" function value "z" and the "kth-solution" according to the Riemann surface.

As you can see, the analytical solution is scalar, so im working with ContourPlot.

In the Mathemtaica Help->ProductLog->Applications is a simular Plot. Its the Potential Field of this Capacitor.

The imaginary Part of this Function represents the potential field, the real part represents the electrical field (but as a scalar function).

This are my Contours:

```
cont := Table[\[Phi]re[{i, 0}], {i, -5, 14, .5}]
```

This are some parameters:

```
plotsizeminx := 5
plotsizemaxx := 7
plotsizeminy := 8.5
plotsizemaxy := 8.5
```

This is the Plot:

```
contplot = 
 ContourPlot[\[Phi]re[{x, y}], {x, -plotsizeminx, 
   plotsizemaxx}, {y, -plotsizeminy, plotsizemaxy}, 
  Epilog -> {Black, Thickness[0.01], 
    Line[{{-plotsizeminx, Pi}, {0, Pi}}], 
    Line[{{-plotsizemaxx, -Pi}, {0, -Pi}}]}, ContourShading -> False, 
  Contours -> cont, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/1.5, 
  ContourStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.002], Opacity[1]}}]
```

This is a Image of the Plot:
[image: ContourPlot]

So ProductLog switch from the 0th solution to first soltion at a value of pi.

As you can see in the Image i have highlighted the area at the level of pi. So cause of the switching from the 0th to the first solution there is some kind of gap in the lines of the Plot.

It is crucial for my work to get rid of this gaps.

Do you have a idea how to get rid of this gaps?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding `Exclusions -> None`?

Comment: This was the perfect Solution. Thank you for your Answer.

Comment: On a mathematical note: I presume you're aware of the Wright $\omega$ function?

Comment: No, i dont know this function.